# modify Xaxis in highcharts

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, highcharts

How can I introduce in the highcharts code an array that comes from a php code?

In the next code php I generate 4 arrays, 3 for Data (TMax ($rows), TMin ($rows1) and Rain ($rows2) and the last one for the days of the consulting ($dia).

```
$sth = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT City,TMax, Day(Date) As Dia FROM Meteo2 where City= '" . $_SESSION["City"] ."' AND Data BETWEEN '" . split($_SESSION["date8"]) ."' AND '" . split($_SESSION["date9"]) ."'order by Date");

$rows = array();
$dia = array();
$dia['name'] = 'Dia';
$rows['name'] = 'TMAX';

$rows['color'] = '#FF0000';
$cont=1;
while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($sth)) {
$rows['data'][] = $r['TMax'];
$dia['categories'][] = $r['Dia'];
}
$sth = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT City,TMin FROM Meteo2 where City= '" .   $_SESSION["City"] ."' AND Data BETWEEN '" . split($_SESSION["date8"]) ."' AND '" . split($_SESSION["date9"]) ."'order by Date");

$rows1 = array();
$rows1['name'] = 'TMIN';
$rows1['color'] = '#00FFFF';
$rows1['var valueSuffix'] = 'ºC';
while($rr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
$rows1['data'][] = $rr['TMin'];
}

mysqli_query($con,"SELECT City,Rain FROM Meteo2 where City= '" . $_SESSION["City"] ."' AND Data BETWEEN '" . split($_SESSION["date8"]) ."' AND '" . split($_SESSION["date9"]) ."'order by Date");

$rows2 = array();
$rows2['name'] = 'RAIN';
$rows2['type'] = 'column';
$rows2['color'] = '#4572A7';
$rows2['var valueSuffix'] = 'mm';
$rows2['var yAxis'] = 2;
while($rr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
$rows2['data'][] = $rr['Rain'];
}

$result = array();
array_push($result,$rows2);
array_push($result,$rows1);
array_push($result,$rows);
array_push($result,$dia);
print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);


mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

When I plot the chart, I can see the line of rain, TMax, TMin, but in the Xaxis by default I have 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15....and what I need is the information of $dia inside categories[]

and when i check the browser I see categories empty...
    xAxis: {
    categories:  []
    },

but in the highchart code I have

```
xAxis: {
categories: ['<?php echo $dia?>']
},
```

any help please????

Here I show the highcharts code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>www.meteo4u.com/consultaNouformat.html</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php
$city = $_POST["City"];


session_start();
$_SESSION['City'] = $_POST['City'];
$_SESSION['date8'] = $_POST['date8'];
$_SESSION['date9'] = $_POST['date9'];
?>


$(function () {
var chart;

$(document).ready(function() {
$.getJSON("mysql-highcharts.php", function(json) {

chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
renderTo: 'container',
type: 'spline',
marginRight: 130,
marginBottom: 25
},
title: {
text: 'Temperatura Maxima, Temperatura Minima i Precipitacio a <?php echo $city ?>',
x: -20 //center
},
xAxis: {
categories:  [<?php echo $dia?>]
},
yAxis: [{
labels: {
format: '{value}°C',
style: {
color: '#FF0000'
}
},
title: {
text: 'Temperatura Maxima',
style: {
color: '#FF0000'
}
}
},{title: {
text: 'Temperatura Minima',
style: {
color: '#00FFFF'
}
}
},{labels: {
format: '{value} mm',
style: {
color: '#4572A7'
}
},
title: {
text: 'Precipitacio',
style: {
color: '#4572A7'
}
},opposite: true
}],
tooltip: {
formatter: function() {
return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
this.x +': '+ this.y;
}
},
legend: {
layout: 'vertical',
align: 'right',
verticalAlign: 'top',
x: -10,
y: 100,
borderWidth: 0
},
credits:{
text: 'meteo4u.com',
href:'http://meteo4u.com',
itemStyle: {    
fontSize: '40px'
}
},
series: json
});
});
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have such mess in your code.. I advice to start with reading tutorials about PHP and JS, sorry, but that's true - you are messing around with getJSON and <php> tags. Simply try `categories: json[3]`.

Comment: Sorry, can you put me an example of how manage it? I only want to modify the x data, insert the days of consulting. What does it mean  3 inside json?

Comment: That's why I suggest to learn more about PHP and JS, you would know what is `[3]`. It's fourth element in json array.

Comment: I understand that $results has 4 elements, $rows,$rows1,$rows2 and $day. $day is the fourth element. What now how I call it in categories? any example please, or reference?

Comment: Just replace in your code: `xAxis: { categories:  [<?php echo $dia?>] },` with `xAxis: { categories:  json[3] },` - as I said in my first comment.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work. I tried it yesterday after your first comment, and now again, but doesn't work with { categories: json[3] }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like $dia is an array is an array, containing an entry called 'categories'. I don't think you can somply echo the array variable in your highcharts code, as dia only exists in php on the server. You are returning the categories inside your json object in the 3rd entry of the array

```
array_push($result,$dia);
```

This means you have to read the categories out of the returned json in your highcharts code. Your code is hard to follow, but try this:

```
xAxis: {
    categories:  json[3]['categories'];
},
```

However, I am worried about this line:

```
series: json
```

The returned json does not just contain series definitions as it contains the categories as well. It may work, but is not very clean code.

Comment: Thank you SteveP for your help. I have used your code but still it appears empty when I plot it, again by default in the Xaxis it plots 0,1,2,3,4... and in the browser I have categories: []

Comment: So where is $dia set in your highcharts code ? You need to call the other php.

Comment: I put the information of $dia in $result = array();
array_push($result,$rows2);
array_push($result,$rows1);
array_push($result,$rows);
array_push($result,$dia);
print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

Comment: I've re-written my answer. Your code is hard to follow, but I think I understand what is going on now.

Comment: Thank you Steve! it runs now with xAxis: {
        categories:  json[3]['categories']
    },

Comment: you can see the example in http://www.meteo4u.com/consultaNouformat.html , chosing the period, Poblacio (city in catalan) and push "Mostrar Grafica". Thank you